# PHP call non-existing, undefined methods/functions

Tags: php, function, methods

I have seen that there are some dynamic methods we can use in PHP frameworks that ***I guess*** which are actually does not exist, specially in frameworks like Laravel and Magento.

Ex:

```
MyClass::whereCity('london')->get();
```

What I want to do is call `whereCity()` method without actually defining it. Then capture the `City` part to filter results, so there might be lot of function calls such as `whereId()`, `whereName()`, `whereCountry()`, etc. Is it possible?

**PS: Please note that I'm not looking for Magento or Laravel solution, those are mentioned for easy comprehension of the question. I want general solution that can be implemented with any PHP solution.**

Comment: No. The method has to be defined.

Comment: In Laravel write MyClass::where('city','london')->get();

Comment: @RaviHirani you misunderstood my question. I don't want the Laravel way. I'm asking is it possible to call undefined functions which can be dynamically defined.

Comment: @JanakaDombawela: Nope. It is not possible bro.

Comment: If you have a class, you can use `Class::__callStatic($methodName, $args)` and do things in there, depending on the method name. But that is a really really bad idea, since you still need to define the functionality, but without any clear definition. Why would you need this,  in the first place? What is the end goal?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Just out of curiosity. I have seen some of implementations like this in many PHP frameworks, I initially guessed it might be some voodoo magic. Boy I was wrong.

Comment: No, it's definitely some voodoo magic, you were right the first time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP has some [Magic Methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) that you can use to have dynamic methods.
In particular [`__call`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) and [`__callStatic`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic).

#### Eg from the documentation:

```php
<?php
class MethodTest
{
    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        // Note: value of $name is case sensitive.
        echo "Calling object method '$name' "
             . implode(', ', $arguments). "\n";
    }

    /**  As of PHP 5.3.0  */
    public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments)
    {
        // Note: value of $name is case sensitive.
        echo "Calling static method '$name' "
             . implode(', ', $arguments). "\n";
    }
}

$obj = new MethodTest;
$obj->runTest('in object context');

MethodTest::runTest('in static context');  // As of PHP 5.3.0
?>


// Calling object method 'runTest' in object context
// Calling static method 'runTest' in static context
```

Please consider you still have to generate an algorithm to handle all the cases.